# ExtJS show message if Caps Lock is on

Tags: javascript, extjs

I want to add a message if user turns on the caps lock while entering password. This is what I've tried so far.

```
 {
     xtype:'textfield',
     itemId: 'field_password_login',
     fieldLabel: 'Password',
     inputType: 'password',
     allowBlank: false,
     listeners:
     {
         keypress: function(tf, e)
         {
             if (e.getKey() != 13 && e.getKey() != 10 && e.getKey() != 127)
             {
                 if ((!e.shiftKey && (e.getKey() >= 65 && e.getKey() <= 90)) || ((e.getKey() >= 97 && e.getKey() <= 122) && e.shiftKey))
                 {
                     Ext.getCmp("app_idCAPSIndicator").setText("CAPS LOCK is ON");
                     Ext.getDom("app_idCAPSIndicator").style.color = "navy";

                 }
                 else
                 {
                     Ext.getCmp("app_idCAPSIndicator").setText("");
                 }
             }
             if (e.getKey() == 13)
             {
                 Ext.Msg.alert("Enter Pressed");
             }
         }
     }
 },
 {
     xtype: 'label',
     fieldLabel: '',
     labelWidth: 90,
     labelAlign: 'left',
     labelSeperator: '',
     id: 'app_idCAPSIndicator'
 }
```

But it does not work. I get no error message to know what is happening. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I solved it using: `listeners: {
                        specialkey: function(field, e) {
                            if (e.getKey() == 20 && !toolTip.isVisible()) {
                                toolTip.show();
                            } else {
                                toolTip.hide();
                            }
                        }
                    },`

Answer (score 2):

Add enableKeyEvents: true, this true to enable the proxying of key events for the HTML input field

```
{
     xtype:'textfield',
     itemId: 'field_password_login',
     fieldLabel: 'Password',
     inputType: 'password',
     allowBlank: false,
     enableKeyEvents: true,
     listeners:
     {
         keypress: function(tf, e)
         {
             if (e.getKey() != 13 && e.getKey() != 10 && e.getKey() != 127)
             {
                 if ((!e.shiftKey && (e.getKey() >= 65 && e.getKey() <= 90)) || ((e.getKey() >= 97 && e.getKey() <= 122) && e.shiftKey))
                 {
                     Ext.getCmp("app_idCAPSIndicator").setText("CAPS LOCK is ON");
                     Ext.getDom("app_idCAPSIndicator").style.color = "navy";

                 }
                 else
                 {
                     Ext.getCmp("app_idCAPSIndicator").setText("");
                 }
             }
             if (e.getKey() == 13)
             {
                 Ext.Msg.alert("Enter Pressed");
             }
         }
     }
 },
```

Comment: It works but I have to turn caps lock on and start typing to show the message. How can I set alert when caps lock is turned on? Without typing...

Comment: if you change the listener to keyup you can detect the press of caps lock, keypress dosn't detect the caps lock key

Comment: I tried with `keyup` it does not work. It shows now CAPS LOCK is ON as soon as I start writing regardless if the caps lock on or off.

Answer (score 0):

The [Ext.event.Event](https://docs.sencha.com/ext/6.5.1/modern/Ext.event.Event.html) has constants to many types of keys, including caps lock. Also, there is a specific event handler for this case, which is *specialkey*. So, expanding on Moataz's answer:

```
{
     xtype:'textfield',
     itemId: 'field_password_login',
     fieldLabel: 'Password',
     inputType: 'password',
     allowBlank: false,
     enableKeyEvents: true,
     listeners:
     {
         specialkey: function(tf, e)
         {
                 if (e.getKey() == Ext.event.Event.CAPS_LOCK)
                 {
                     Ext.getCmp("app_idCAPSIndicator").setText("CAPS LOCK is ON");
                     Ext.getDom("app_idCAPSIndicator").style.color = "navy";
                 }
         }
     }
 }
```

You should use constants instead of numbers to improve readability. That's one reason why Ext.event.Event has key constants.

[ExtJS documentation](https://docs.sencha.com/ext/6.5.1/classic/Ext.event.Event.html#method-isSpecialKey) defines the keys considered to be special.